# Custom decoder for AWS API Gateway using circe

Tags: json, scala, aws-lambda, circe

I would like to create a custom decoder for AWS API Gateway using `circe-core`. I have the following code:

```
case class APIGatewayInput(body:Result[Body], queryParams: Map[String,String], pathParams: Map[String,String])

object ApiGatewayInput {
  implicit val decodeApiGatewayInput = Decoder.instance { c =>
    val body:Result[Body] = c.get[Body]("body")
    val queryParams = c.field("queryStringParameters").as[Map[String,String]](decoder???)
    APIGatewayInput(body, queryParams, similarForPathParams)
  }
}
```

I know that `Result` has methods to parse data to `Map[K,V]` and `as` requires a `Decoder` (which is a little confusing) and I can convert it to a `Map[String, String]`

How can I use the API to convert to an existing scala collection type with the `HCursor` instead of a custom type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 import io.circe._, io.circe.generic.auto._, io.circe.parser._, 
 io.circe.syntax._
 case class Test(a: Map[String,String])
 val map = Test(Map("a"->"1","2"->"2")).asJson
 val hcursor = map.hcursor

 val m = hcursor.downField("a").as[Map[String,String]]
 println(m) // Right(Map(a -> 1, 2 -> 2))
```